# method startsWith subString

Tags: java

I could not get around the problem, it seems something trivial but could not catch it..

```
public static void handleClient(){

System.out.println("Opening PORT...");
Socket link = null;

try{

link =servSock.accept();
Scanner input = new Scanner(link.getInputStream());
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(link.getOutputStream(),true);


String message = input.nextLine();
String username = null;
if (message.startstWith("username"))

{
    username = message.subString(7);
    output.println("Your username is: "+ username);
    System.out.println(username+" is connecting...");

    message = input.nextLine();

    while (!message.equals("*END*"))
        {
        System.out.println(username +" Says: "+message);
        output.println("we received your message..");
        }



}else{

output.println("PLEASE VERIFY hostname...");

}
```

I am receiving what comes from the socket stream and save it as String

String message = input.nextLine();

and here is the  result when I compile it

```
    C:\Users\==\Desktop\anoterTest>javac TCPServer.java
TCPServer.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
    if (message.startstWith("username"))
               ^
symbol:   method startstWith(String)
location: variable message of type String
TCPServer.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
            username = message.subString(0,8);
                              ^
symbol:   method subString(int,int)
location: variable message of type String
2 errors

C:\Users\==\Desktop\anoterTest>
```

Comment: For the starters use some IDE.

Comment: @AniketThakur I think you mean "startsters".

Answer (score 2):

`startstWith` should be `startsWith` (there is a spelling mistake)

and

`subString` should be `substring`

Java methods are case sensitive

Comment: Thank you guys.... I use text editor as our university asking us to know the syntax as our names, thats why I did not catch the spelling.Thank you again

Comment: @user877900: That explains why you didn't spot it when typing - but you should be able to spot it when the compiler points it out to you, and you then check exactly what you've written against the javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled `startsWith` as `startstWith`. You also misspelled `substring` as `subString` - capitalization matters.

Answer (score 0):

[**String.startsWith**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29)

```
 if (message.startsWith("username"))
```

instead of

```
if (message.startstWith("username"))
```